# Legal calls and determination of overloaded functions in Java

Tags: java, object

I'm doing some self-study over the summer, and I came across this problem I'm unsure of, and I was wondering if anyone could help out.  I'm unsure of the last number, but I included my previous answers if anyone would be willing to check those as well.  This is not homework for any class, I just want to make sure I understand what I'm doing before I move forward.

I'm considering the following definitions:

```
1. void m (Object o, long x, long y)
2. void m (String s, int x, long y)
3. void m (Object o, int x, long y)
4. void m (String s, long x, int y)
```

which these declarations:

```
Object o;
String v;
int a;
long b;
```

and I'm examining these calls:

```
m(v,a,b); Calls 2, because it is the most specific.
m(v,a,a); Not legal, because 2 and 4 could both be called (not specific enough).
m(v,b,a); Calls 4, because it is the most specific. 
m(v,b,b); Calls 1, because it is the only one that will fit (long cannot shorten to int).
m(o,b,b); Calls 1, similar reasoning as above answer.
m(o,a,a); Unsure.  I'm not sure of the precedence.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it yourself? If the question is *why* overloads get picked, that's one thing; but if the question is which get picked, that's very easy to test.

Comment: It's sort of a matter of both, but you're right, I didn't even think to test it.  It would be really easy to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple a case of "most specific" again. Option 3 is chosen for the same reason that your second call is illegal. `m(v,a,a)` can't choose between `m(String,long,int)` and `m(String,int,long)` because they're equally specific. Each one requires a single widening conversion of one of the arguments. `m(o,a,a)`, on the other hand, can choose between `m(Object,long,long)` and `m(Object,int,long)`. One of those requires two widening conversions. The other requires only one, making it the most specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I should have realized that Object couldn't fit String.  If I had realized that I would have immediately been led to 3.

Answer (score 2):

The last one will call 3. As the first argument is Object, it can only pick one of the methods with Object as the first argument -- so that leaves either 1 or 3 as options. The third argument `int` fits into the `long` so that is legal in both cases. The second argument can be exactly fitted into 3, whereas it has to be widened to fit into 1. The compiler gives preference to exact matching over widening.

Your previous answers are correct as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I didn't realize that Object could only fit Object, but String could fit Object/String.  Once you pointed that out, I immediately understand why it's 3.

Answer (score 0):

m(v,b,b); Calls 1, because it is the only one that will fit (long cannot shorten to int).

Another reason for this calling 1 is due to Polymorphism and singly rooted hierarchy of Java. A String (or any object) is a descendent of the Object class. Any method that takes Object as an argument can take a String - the essence of Polymorphism.